# error while writing file after adonis analysis

Tags: r, vegan, phyloseq

I am trying to write output from permutation analysis by using below code but it shows error, could you please suggest how I can resolve this error?

```
R code

###adonis_calculation
BC <- phyloseq::distance(phyloseq_prop, "bray")
pmv =adonis(BC ~Season*Region, as(sample_data(physeqN3), "data.frame"),permutations = 5000)
pmv

write.table(pmv, "permutation.16s.Root.txt")

Error:

              Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)
Season          1    1.2435 1.24348  17.229 0.07405  2e-04 ***
Region          2    5.3491 2.67457  37.058 0.31855  2e-04 ***
Season:Region   2    1.3222 0.66110   9.160 0.07874  2e-04 ***
Residuals     123    8.8773 0.07217         0.52866
Total         128   16.7921                 1.00000
---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :
  cannot coerce class ‘"adonis"’ to a data.frame
Calls: write.table ... data.frame -> as.data.frame -> as.data.frame.default
Execution halted
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you try `library(broom); write.table(tidy(pmv), "permutation.16s.Root.txt")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is not in data.frame format, an option is to capture the output with `capture.output`

```
capture.output(pmv, file = "permutation.16s.Root.txt")
```

---

Using a small reproducible example

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
pmv <- adonis(dune ~ Management*A1, data = dune.env)
capture.output(pmv, file  = "/Users/akrun/tmp/permutation.16s.Root.txt")
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The element you want is the `aov.tab`. You can tidy the output with *broom* . There are some 'NA' that can be easily eliminated.

```
library(broom)
fit_adonis_before$aov.tab %>% broom::tidy()
```

As an extra step you can print to the screen an almost ready table with *formattable*

```
library(formattable)
fit_adonis_before$aov.tab %>% broom::tidy() %>% 
    formattable::formattable()
```